# VBA Dialogue FileFilter Partial File Name

Tags: vba, filesystems

I have a directory with several .txt files. Let's say

```
hi.txt
hello.txt
hello_test.txt
test.txt
```

Using a file dialogue in VBA, how can I filter to show only "*test.txt" matching files (ie last two) in the dropdown? Or can I only use *. filters?

The following seems it should work but does not:

```
Sub TestIt()
   Dim test As Variant 'silly vba for not having a return type..
   test = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="test (*test.txt), *test.txt")
End Sub
```

edit: clarifying in case this wasn't clear: I want to filter "*test.txt" instead of "*.txt" files so I can only select from hello_test.txt and test.txt in the chooser.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I see that you are concerned about putting text in the file name box, but that is exactly what you need to do and appears to be the norm for your situation. I got hung up on the exact same issue.

This is what I used:

```
Public Sub Browse_Click()

Dim fileName As String
Dim result As Integer
Dim fs

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    .Title = "Select Test File"
    .Filters.Add "Text File", "*.txt"
    .FilterIndex = 1
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = "*test*.*"

    result = .Show

    If (result <> 0) Then
        fileName = Trim(.SelectedItems.Item(1))

        Me!txtFileLocation = fileName

    End If
End With
```

Comment: Thank you, this does exactly what I am trying to do - it is strange how the process to implement this works (??). You set the filter via a "initialFileName" filter... I guess as long as it works :-)

Answer (score 3):

How about filedialog?

```
Dim dlgOpen As FileDialog
Set dlgOpen = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
With dlgOpen
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .InitialFileName = "Z:\docs\*t*.*x*"
    .Show
End With
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213120(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: That does not filter which files are shown but rather puts text in the "text area" of the textbox.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are trying? Paste this in a module and run the sub `OpenMyFile`

```
Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
"GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long

Private Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize       As Long
    hwndOwner         As Long
    hInstance         As Long
    lpstrFilter       As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As String
    nMaxCustFilter    As Long
    nFilterIndex      As Long
    lpstrFile         As String
    nMaxFile          As Long
    lpstrFileTitle    As String
    nMaxFileTitle     As Long
    lpstrInitialDir   As String
    lpstrTitle        As String
    flags             As Long
    nFileOffset       As Integer
    nFileExtension    As Integer
    lpstrDefExt       As String
    lCustData         As Long
    lpfnHook          As Long
    lpTemplateName    As String
End Type

Sub OpenMyFile()
    Dim OpenFile As OPENFILENAME
    Dim lReturn As Long
    Dim strFilter As String

    OpenFile.lStructSize = Len(OpenFile)

    '~~> Define your filter here
    strFilter = "Text File (*test.txt)" & Chr(0) & "*test.txt" & Chr(0)

    With OpenFile
        .lpstrFilter = strFilter
        .nFilterIndex = 1
        .lpstrFile = String(257, 0)
        .nMaxFile = Len(.lpstrFile) - 1
        .lpstrFileTitle = .lpstrFile
        .nMaxFileTitle = .nMaxFile
        .lpstrInitialDir = "C:\Users\Siddharth Rout\Desktop\"
        .lpstrTitle = "My FileFilter Open"
        .flags = 0
    End With

    lReturn = GetOpenFileName(OpenFile)

    If lReturn = 0 Then
        '~~> User cancelled
        MsgBox "User cancelled"
    Else
        MsgBox "User selected" & ":=" & OpenFile.lpstrFile
        '
        '~~> Rest of your code
        '
    End If
End Sub
```