# VBA 2007 Filedialog Adding Filters

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2007 and trying to filter the FileDialog list of files by using a Filter.  While debugging, the code returns an error on the .Filters.Add line: Run-time error '5': Invalid procedure call or argument.  I've scoured StackOverflow and Microsoft.  The .Add method appears to be correct.

```
Dim fn As Object
Set fn = Application.FileDialog(3)
With fn
    .InitialFileName = "C:\BillData\"
    .Title = "Select input file"
    .Filters.Clear
    .Filters.Add "Bill Files", "ccc.*"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialView = msoFileDialogViewDetails
End With
```

If I skip that line of code, everything else seems to work properly.  Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are looking for files like "test.ccc" or "myresource.ccc", your filter should be "*.ccc".  If you actually have a bunch of files named just ccc of different file types like "ccc.txt", "ccc.jpg" "ccc.doc" etc, you would need to filter for those through InitialFileName [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10821545/2832561).